# Data Visualization: Best tools to generate simple charts in PDF with Javascript or Python

Tags: javascript, python, pdf, data-visualization

I'm building an app that will talk to a real estate API to fetch info about housing within a certain area. Then for each query it will generate a PDF doc based on the returned data that has two simple charts, a bar chart and line chart.

I'm wondering if it's worth paying for something like FusionCharts or if there's a free library to work with. I'm a fairly novice programmer who mainly works in JS/jQuery and Python. I'm pretty much new to Data Visualization.

Comment: If you're comfortable with Python, then there's `matplotlib`.

Comment: any updates to this? This answer might be a bit outdated but I'm currently looking to do something similar in python and looking for good solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [D3.js](http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/making-a-bar-chart/) to create all kind of charts in client side rather than generating chart in server  side. You are also working with an API, so D3.js will be very useful. If you are a Python lover, you can use d3 via the [d3py library](https://github.com/mikedewar/d3py). And you can generate pdfs in javascript via [jsPDF](http://parall.ax/products/jspdf).